# ContextMenuStrip scrolling up and down arrows information c#

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip

I've been busying myself with the ContextMenuStrip class lately and I've noticed something while trying to add a scrolling option to my CMS. So, the control itels adds automatically those little up and down arrows on the top and the bottom of the drop down menu when the number of the items in it exceeds the maximum size that can be displayed:

[image]

Unfortunately I can't seem to find any information about those arrows and I'd like to manipulate a couple of actions with them. My question is where I coul'd find some aditional info about those buttons and if it's even possible to work with them in some way. I've also noticed that they remove the focus from the drop down meny when clicked, which appeared to be a problem for my way of working...
Thanks for any information!

P.S.: The whole poin is that I want to create (or rather manipulate) a scrolling option for the ContextMenuStrip and so far I'm having a pretty tough time. Never thought it would be THAT hard... :D

Comment: Personally, I would reconsider my design if I had that many items in a Context menu - there is a need and a place for a context menu, in this case, I'd suggest using something else to fit in with your design?

Comment: @Hexie I'd be glad if you could suggest something more reasonable... Since it's not that much of a deal to just have an extremely long list with items to select and just be able to scroll it like a normal list, but I need it to be accessible via right click at any point... Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yeah sure, if you could elaborate on what the scope of these options are for - where would they be used and what is the purpose you trying to achieve? i.e. is it feasible to add then to an "options" list within the UI - the options would really depend on the overall goal of your idea?

Comment: @Hexie All of those items are actually valuable data that the user has input into a file and he needs to be able to access them at any point of the work and to put them wherever he wants (which is at many places).
The contextmenustrip has been just fine so far until the items got too much to handle...
Plus the count should not be a problem, since the user should be able to just scroll trough all the data as far as he wants to xD

Comment: What about an "autocomplete box" in the title or top of the application, whereby the user can start typing in what they need (from the file) then the autoComplete box could filter the options out, as the user types, this was showing less options (more accurate) for the user. They can then click on the item they wish and you could add it?

Comment: I have found some information about your suggestion but I think it's not suitable with the needs. See, I have to work with a datagridview and the feature I'm using this long list for is actually somthing like a dictionary. The point is, that the user will have a lot of data displayed each time and he has to show which cell contains some valuable data, that actually represents one of the items in the list (from those items that are in the file). So then he can right click on the cell and just tell the program a resemplance of which item the value in the cell is...

Comment: I understand, but it still sounds like you could use the suggestion (as it's needed to be data bound). Regardless, I think the main issue you need to figure out is how to reduce that list. The first idea that's comes to me is to filter it out, and what better way than letting the user do that - they know what they looking for regardless...
It's like displaying everything in a database, rather than filtering it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112336/discussion-between-d-petrov-and-hexie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments and with the OP, this design might need to re-thought.

The adopted approach will be to use an AutoComplete box, linked to a datasource, whereby the user can type in the field they are wanting (this is known) and select the field from the suggestions displayed.

This would then add the field to the same area as previously described - providing, a faster and more UX friendly way of doing this;

Some URL's to help with autocomplete:

- [TextBox AutoComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Youtube video on using a TextBox AutoComplete](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2suYQr6ebI)
- [ToolStrip Text Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriptextbox.aspx) (using autoComplete within a ToolStrip TextBox)

Comment: Any further info found? :D

Comment: @D.Petrov The last bit of info I found was sent to you on the "chat" that we had going, I hope that helps you further.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I guess I'll have to construct the 'pop-up' myself or just rethink my way of working... Head up! :D